# Converting table to list grouping 3 rows

Tags: jquery, html

In SharePoint it has a nasty habit of using nested tables everywhere. I want to use a jQuery carousel on one of them and it does not work with tables. So I need to convert a table to a list. This is not a problem as I found some jQuery that will do it for me. Namely:

```
var list = $("<ul/>");      
$('#tab1').find("tr").each(function() {         
    var p = $(this).children().map(function() {             
        return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";         
    });          
    list.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(p).join("") + "</li>");     
});      
$('#tab1').replaceWith(list);
```

The table structure is like:

```
<table id="test1">
    <tr><td>Help 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Me 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Please 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Help 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Me 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Please 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Help 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Me 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Please 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery above converts each `tr` to a `li` item. But for my needs I need to group into 3 rows. So the output should be:

```
<ul id="test1">
    <li>
        <p class="p1">Help 1</p>
        <p class="p2">Me 1</p>
        <p class="p3">Please 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="p1">Help 2</p>
        <p class="p2">Me 2</p>
        <p class="p3">Please 2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="p1">Help 3</p>
        <p class="p2">Me 3</p>
        <p class="p3">Please 3</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I need to add a class to each row and group them in threes. So I need to know, using the jQuery statement above, if it is possible to use a counter to iterate through the list in the `children().map` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this more explicit version ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGwyz/)):

```
var list = $("<ul/>");      
var listitem = null;

// iterate over each cell (not each row)
$('#tab1').find("tr > td").each(function(i) {

    // starting with the first item, start a new listitem every three items
    // and append it to the ul
    if(i%3 == 0){
        listitem = $("<li/>");
        list.append(listitem);
    }

    // append the current item as a paragraph to the listitem
    var p = "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";         
    listitem.append(p);

});      

// replace the table with the ul
$('#tab1').replaceWith(list);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, I adapted it as there was a number of table cells in each row that I needed to take care of but this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target = $("#test1");
var results = [];
target.find("tr > td").each(function(i) {
    var obj = $(this);
    if(i%3 == 0) results.push("<li>");
    results.push("<p>");
    results.push(obj.html());
    results.push("</p>");
    if(i%3 == 2) results.push("</li>");
});
var results_in_html = results.join("");
```

looks messy, but this is more runtime optimized i guess, see:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to group your `<tr/>`

```
var list = $("<ul/>");

while($("#test1 tr").length > 0)
{
    var td = $("#test1 tr").slice(0, 3).detach().find("td");
    var nowP = td.map(function(index, elm){
        return $("<p/>", {html:$(elm).text(), class:"p" + (index+1)}).get();
    });
    list.append($("<li/>").append(nowP));
}

$("#test1").replaceWith(list);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6QMqA/)**