# JQuery - Remove specific element tags (but not the HTML) from within 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table (with 2 columns) I want to convert into a list.

So far I can wrap the `tr`s in `li` tags eg:

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
  $(this).wrap('<li />');
});
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to simply then strip the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags out from withing `this` just leaving whatever other written content there is?

I have tried messing around with `remove()` and `replaceWith()` but they remove everything from between the tags as well.

Is there a way to just target the tags themselves?

EDIT: HTML:

This:

```
<tr>
 <td>Lorem</td>
 <td>Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Dolar</td>
 <td>Sit</td>
</tr>
```

Becomes:

```
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Dolar Sit</li>
```

*obviously will deal with the spaces between the words later

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML structure?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst yep added above, along with what I want to achieve

Comment: Cool - I'll add an answer in a moment.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074393/converting-table-to-list-grouping-3-rows

Comment: @MeltingDog You are trying to create a n html structure which is invalid. li's cannot be direct child to a table or a tr. You need to proabably convert it to ul - li instead and remove the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        console.log('<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>')
        $(this).html('<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/wwSGV/1

Comment: This will result in invalid HTML. You should n't create `li` as children of `tr`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/m3emb/1/

**html**

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Lorem</td>
 <td>Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Dolar</td>
 <td>Sit</td>
</tr>
</table>

<ul></ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $list = $('ul');
$('table tr').each(function() {
  $list.append($('<li />').html($(this).text()));
});
$('table').remove();
```